# how to post data from one php to another without reloading it?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, post

I have a html page with two iframes in them .there is a button on first iframe which should reload second iframe with some data which is sent on the click of the button ..but the first iframe containing the button should not reload.how can i make it possible ?

```
<?php 
             // code to send data without reloading page but instead reloading another iframe with sent data?>
```

Comment: Please post an example - the 'code' you have posted is useless

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iframe, use javascript to submit the form by some sort of ajax method:

`<form [...] onsubmit="sendAjax(); return false;">`

The `return false` part prevents the form from submitting (as long as you don't have some sort of errors in your sendAjax() function.

Since it is going to take a bit of time for the server to process the request that should show up when iframe 2 refreshes, you could possibly use evilone's suggestion and use sessions to see if some sort of session variable has been set. Then in frame 2, make the javascript wait say 500 ms before refreshing and then refresh the page. You could loop this refreshing process to make sure that the session variable has been set and that the correct output will be sent.